# Does not contain definition of button in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to use `id` in code behind in aspx.cs. Not sure how to use it.

```
<input name="SelectAllButton" type="button" id="SelectAllButton"  value="DeSelect All" class="EButton" title="DeSelect All" />
```

aspx.cs code

```
SelectAllButton.ID = "SelectAllButton";
```

But If use `webbutton` then it works but I do not want to use it.

```
<cc1:WebButton ID="SelectAllButton" runat="server"></cc1:WebButton>
```

Comment: add `runat="server"` to `input` in order to use it in code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ASP Web Forms, you should use the ASP input types. `<input />` is a client-side HTML input and won't be seen by the server.

I believe you will want to use asp:Button type.

E.g.
`<asp:Button id="SelectAllButton" Text="DeSelect All" class="EButton" runat="server" />`